# presentModalViewController is taking over whole iPad screen, not just right hand side?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, ekeventkit

I'm using the `APSplitViewController` on the iPad to get two sides.  When working within the right hand side I have a viewController that sits inside a `UINavigationController`.

When I modally present `EKEventEditViewController` (as it has to be modal) it doesn't stay inside the bounds of the right hand side navController but takes over the whole iPad display, and things start getting worse from there...

Is there a way to keep the modal view within the context of the local `UINavigationController` I'm working with on the right hand side of the screen?

```
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[[EKEventEditViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] autorelease];
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];
```

PS. This is actually an issue for any simple view controller (not just EKEventEditViewController) in fact.  That is when trying to use a presentModalViewController.  A code example of how to make "presentModalViewController" work so it only takes up the right hand side would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, it's better to update rightViewController of your APSplitViewController with EKEventEditViewController to display EKEventEditViewController in bounds of right side.

Comment: presentModalViewController presents view only fullscreen or as form in the center of screen, near 500:600 px.

Comment: do you mean to kind of "drop" the existing controller out of the right hand side and put EKEventEditViewController as a new one?  if yes, I'm just wondering what would be the mechanism to return to the previous view controller?

Comment: PS. This is actually an issue for any simple view controller (not just EKEventEditViewController) in fact.

Comment: if you replace existing controler, you're responsible in implementing "mechanism to return to the previous view controller"

Comment: ok, so do you mean in your answer to kind of "drop" the existing controller out of the right hand side and put EKEventEditViewController as a new one? (as opposed to pushing on a new one, or using a modal view)

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you write your own custom presentModalViewController methods.

Comment: still stuck on this - are you able to give me a few bullet points of the concept you had in mind? thanks